# sync sqlite database from server database (mysql) in iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, sql-server, sqlite, ios5

I am using `SQLite` database in iPhone application. I want to *sync* application `SQLite` database from `MySQL server` database.

Any ideas about how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Implement a webservice to provide data on the server, then deploy a client to consume the service. In your application you may use the WSClient++ (http://wsclient.neurospeech.com/) or some other API.